# Postbacks and output caching on user controls

Tags: asp.net, caching, webforms, outputcache

There is a well known issue with using output caching on aspx pages which postback, where Asp.Net returns the cached page, instead executing the postback logic

I came across what seems like an elegant solution  [here](http://www.justagile.com/blogs/posts/making-asp-net-output-cache-work-with-post-back.aspx)

However this doesn't seem to work where the ouput caching in on the user control, rather than a page.

Can anyone suggest a workaround? Or am I missing something

Thanks.